# Vim 8.0 breaks YCM on Windows 10

Tags: microsoft-windows, plugin-you-complete-me, vimscript-python

I was using Vim 7.4 with YCM quite successfully (thank you for YCM!) and just today noticed that Vim 8.0 was out. I downloaded, installed, started and now it complains that "YouCompleteMe unavailable:

> requires VIM compiled with Python (2.6+ or 3.3+) support"

`:version` shows:

```
+python/dyn 
+python3/dyn
```

I am on Windows 10 and used the `.exe` installer.  This was working before with 7.4, but not for 8.0.

Nothing else has changed. Python is on my path, and reports version 3.5.1

Thanks!

Comment: probably it could not load the python*.dll. First, check that your python installation is the same architecture (e.g. 32 vs 64 bit) as your vim installation, second I think it is best to simply throw the python*.dll into your vim installation path.

Comment: I think should ask that on [their issue tracker](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues) you'll be read by people actually developing/contributing to/using the plugin who will probably have a better knowledge of the plugin.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt -- the version mismatch fixed it -- thanks!  I had 32-bit VIM and 64 bit python.  Installing the 64bit vim, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If your output from `:version` is to be believed you have vim build with both python2 and python3 support (dynamic).  This will always trigger YCM to use the python 2 code paths. See the [s:UsingPython2()](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/blob/master/autoload/youcompleteme.vim#L32) function here which decides the path.

```
function! s:UsingPython2()
  " I'm willing to bet quite a bit that sooner or later, somebody will ask us to
  " make it configurable which version of Python we use.
  if has('python')
    return 1
  endif
  return 0
endfunction


let s:using_python2 = s:UsingPython2()
let s:python_until_eof = s:using_python2 ? "python << EOF" : "python3 << EOF"
let s:python_command = s:using_python2 ? "py " : "py3 "
```

Removing the python 2 support should allow YCM to choose the correct version on its own.

Comment: thanks for the insight, but the problem was 32 v 64 bit.  (I tried this first, but no luck).  Thanks!